# "have + verb (present perfect)" in the conditionals

Tags: present-perfect, conditional-constructions

I've come across an interesting thought. Can we say "Had I **have heard**" or "If only I **have heard**". I can't find reference to why this could be wrong.

I noticed that the "**I wish I hadn't ever have shouted at her**" is somewhat correct, where "**have shouted**" is a **Finished Action**.

Can't "**have + verb (present perfect)**" in the conditionals be a finished action too?

Comment: **had not have shouted** sounds totally wrong to my ear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If I would have X'ed" and "if I had X'ed" both express discussion of something that did not happen because some conditions were not met.

"If I have X'ed" expresses discussion of something that isn't happening now because some conditions aren't met, but in a disconnected manner that makes the speaker or "I" seem contemptuous or disbelieving of being questioned.

> If I have had too much to drink then why am I not having problems walking to my car?

The typical way to express that is "I have not X'ed because Y."

> I have not had too much to drink because I am not having problems walking to my car.

Comment: The last sentence doesn't look like a conditional to me. And I purposely didn't include "**would**" in my examples.